# retrieving a "non-key" value using prepared statement (insert statement) in java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, auto-increment, auto-generate

I am well aware of the fact that one can retrieve Auto-generated keys using the prepared Statement with the following syntax:

```
ps = connect.prepareStatement(SQL-insert-Statement , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

But , is it possible to retrieve a non-key value with this insert statement. (IT is Auto generated and auto-incremented but not a Primary key in the database table).

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass an array of column names that you want returned to `prepareStatement`. Maybe that works with MySQL

Comment: how would that syntax look like ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29